# useEffect не вызывается при изменении ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hook, react-hook

При изменении переменной хука `useRef`, не вызывается `useEffect`

Переменные:

```
    const [hiddenLayers, setHiddenLayers] = useState([])
    
    const hiddenLayersRef = useRef([createHiddenLayerElement(1)])
```

Функции:

```
    function addLayer(key) {
        let hiddenLayersTemp = hiddenLayersRef.current
        let elementIndex = hiddenLayersTemp.findIndex(layer => {
            return layer.key === key
        })

        hiddenLayersTemp.splice(elementIndex + 1, 0, createHiddenLayerElement(0))
        
        hiddenLayersRef.current = hiddenLayersTemp
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('test')
        setHiddenLayers([...hiddenLayersRef.current])
    }, [hiddenLayersRef])
```

Но `'test'` выводится только при запуске сайта, в дальнейшем, при вызове функции `addLayer`, `useEffect` не срабатывает. По какой причине так происходит и как это исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`useRef` это не `state` а `useEffect` вызывается только когда происходят изменения в `state` или в зависимостях `state` которые переданы в массив зависимостей для `useEffect`.

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1);

const addCounter = () => {
   setCounter(2); // эта функция вызывает `useEffect` так как `state` обновился.
}
```

_

```
const counter = useRef(1);

const addCounter = () => {
   counter.current = 2; // эта не вызывает `useEffect` так как в `state` нет изменений.
}
```

Пример: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-leaf-5cimg?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Как тогда можно тречить изменения у `useRef` и выполнять определённые действия, когда происходит изменение?

Comment: Никак, `useRef` для этого и создали, что бы хранить там данный, которые не должны тречиться. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Comment: Хорошо, мне нужна переменная, которая останется неизменна при обновлении элемента. Я использовал `useState`, но по какой-то причине при каждом её изменении сначала вызывалась инициализация `useState`, в которой была функция, которая не должна была вызываться заново. Если бы можно было ограничить инициализацию `useState` при каждом изменении, то и неизменная переменная была бы не нужна

Comment: Для неизменных данных используйте `useRef` для данных который должны меняться и как-то перерисовать ваш компонент используйте `useState`. Просто учитывайте это. В вашем коде выше вы пытаетесь отследить изменения на неизменяемом элементе, это условие никогда не выполниться и это логично (уточнение, `useRef` тоже может измениться, но компонент никак на это не отреагирует). Если хотите пример, опишите тут https://codesandbox.io/ пример вашего кода и что вы ожидаете получить.

Comment: Вот код: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-brook-bf0m0?file=/src/App.js
При наведении мышкой на средний `input` элемент (чуть выше\ниже текстбокса), появляются кнопки "+" и "-", если нажать на "+", появляется новый элемент, если на "-", элемент удаляется, но если сначала добавить элемент на "+", потом удалить, нажав на "-" и снова нажать на "+", появится сразу 2 новых элемента. Как я предполагаю, это происходит из-за того, что ререндерится вся функция `LayersInput`, и вместе с ней вызывается инициализация у `useState`

Comment: не могли бы вы посоветовать, что делать в данном случае?

Comment: Я сейчас создаю вам пример кода. Простите работа, раньше не поучилось.

Comment: Примерно так, я не совсем понял, зачем вы стоили эту конструкцию, но задание вполне понятное. Исходя из логики чем проще тем надежней, вот: https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-leaf-5cimg?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Не обязательно именно изменение стейта. Должно поменяться само значение зависимости, переданной в useEffect при очередном рендере . Просто useRef выдаёт один и тот же объект.

Comment: @Александр 
Не совсем так, при удалении элемента в вашем варианте удаляется последний `Input`, тем самым не давая возможность удалить конкретный. А также, не знаете, по какой причине не работал мой вариант?

Comment: Не уверен, что я хочу в этом разбираться. Почему же последний, мы фильтром делаем выборку конкретного элемента. А потом меняем id всех елементов на последовательность в массиве. `setInputs((prevState) => prevState.filter((item) => item.id !== index).map((_, i) => ({ id: i })));`  что бы корректно добавлять новые элементы, если будет вызвана функция добавления.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` срабатывает, когда изменяется значение зависимости при очередном вызове . При этом проверяет только само значение, не делая ни shallow, ни deep сравнение переданного ему объекта. Т.е. в вашем случае он случае вызовется при изменении самого `hiddenLayersRef`.

А `useRef` в свою очередь, отдает вам на каждом вызове один и тот же объект.

Если вам нужно получить вызов эффекта при изменении `hiddenLayersRef.current`, то так и напишите:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('test')
    setHiddenLayers([...hiddenLayersRef.current])
}, [hiddenLayersRef.current])
```

Кроме того, для вызова эффекта нужен вызов `useEffect` с новыми значениями зависимости, т.е. ре-рендер компонента. Т.е. код, меняющий `hiddenLayersRef.current` (вызывающий ваш `addLayer(key)`) должен прямо или триггерить ререндер или самого компонента, или его родителя. Нет вызова - нет реренера с новыми значениями зависимости - нет нового эффекта.

Comment: Если весь объект ref не вызывает `useEffect`, вы думаете свойство этого же объекта его вызовет? Тест:   const [hiddenLayers, setHiddenLayers] = useState([0]);

  const hiddenLayersRef = useRef([1]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("test");
    hiddenLayersRef.current.push(1);
    setHiddenLayers([...hiddenLayersRef.current]);
  }, [hiddenLayersRef.current]);

Comment: @Александр при чем тут вызывает? :) там нет никакой магии. useEffect работает не так, как вы считаете. просто при очередном вызове render еще раз вызывается useEffect, который сравнивает переданные при этом вызове значения зависимостей с переданными значениями на прошлом вызове. Если поменялись - вызвается функция эффекта. Никакого трекинга стейта, и никакого "хитрого автоматического вызова" там нет

Comment: Ну как скажите, я больше поверю докам)

Comment: @PashaPash к сожалению, у меня уже нет возможности воспроизвести тот код, что был раньше, но `[hiddenLayersRef.current]` тоже не вызывал useEffect

Comment: @Александр вот вам простой пример - https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-bartik-ok2jr?file=/src/App.js - в компоненте InnerComponent нет ни зависимостей от state. Кликаете - счетчик в косоли тикает. В доках нигде не сказано что нужны зависимости от стейта. Там стейт используется для того, чтобы вызвать ререндер компонента. Самый простой пример без стейта - смена стейта где-то выше по дереву и обычный вызов рендера.

Comment: Да я же не спорю, как скажите)

Comment: @Coretex он не будет вызывать эффект, если hiddenLayersRef.current не поменялся. Нужно взять отладчик и посмотреть, а не править исходя из неправильных предположений о работе хука :)

Comment: @Александр я просто хотел бы увидеть конкретную фразу в доках, которой вы верите :))

Comment: Вот этой This works because useRef() creates a plain JavaScript object. The only difference between useRef() and creating a {current: ...} object yourself is that useRef will give you the same ref object on every render.

Keep in mind that useRef doesn’t notify you when its content changes. Mutating the .current property doesn’t cause a re-render. If you want to run some code when React attaches or detaches a ref to a DOM node, you may want to use a callback ref instead. Ну и ссылка https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Comment: @Александр ну да, у меня в ответе ровно это и написано - useEffect не срабатывает, потому что в зависимостях при каждом рендере отдается один и тот же объект - useRef will give you the same ref object on every render. Практически дословно.

Comment: @PashaPash и вопрос был в том, *useEffect не вызывается при изменении ref*  он не будет вызывать эффект, если hiddenLayersRef.current не поменялся, даже если он поменяется re-render-a не будет. Потому-что не было изменения жизненного цикла компонента.

Comment: @Александр ну так это очевидно. Я не согласен с частью "useEffect вызывается только когда происходят изменения в state или в зависимостях state которые переданы в массив зависимостей для useEffect" в вашем ответе, а не с фактом невызова ререндера. В той части, что изменения в state не нужны для вызова useEffect, и что никакой прямой связи со state там нет. потому что в текущем виде у вас заявлено, что есть какой-то механизм трекинга "зависимостей state которые переданы в массив зависимостей для useEffect". а его нет, нужен просто ререндер по любой причине + изменение значения зависимости.

Comment: Ну, как скажите)